# Bug on MySQL side with timestamps?

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I think I found a bug on MySQL side.
To reproduce : Just create a table with one column being a timestamp type :

```
create table test
(
    time timestamp null
);
```

Now insert a row with exact date : '2022-03-27 02:00:00':

```
insert into test value ('2022-03-27 02:00:00');
```

I have error :

```
Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '2022-03-27 02:00:00' for column 'time' at row 1
```

Looks like it happens only with date from 2022-03-27 02:00:00 to 2022-03-27 03:00:00 not included.

Could anyone reproduce that and confirm that's a bug from MySQL side ? Or did I miss something here ? Using MySQL 8.0.30 (issue happens with MySQL workbench and CLI so it's not some formatting that would happen before MySQL from any software)

Edit : I have the same error when I try adding the real associated timestamp itself :

```
Incorrect datetime value: '1648346400' for column 'time' at row 1
```

Comment: I think you'll find that is when daylight savings time started. Spring forward...

Comment: I would recommend against using the `TIMESTAMP` data type in MySQL. Apart from having issues with the server time offset, it will run out of values in 2038. Use `DATETIME` instead.

Comment: That's exactly what I did after struggling 4 hours with that ahah.. Problem is that datetime is 8 bytes instead of 4 but anyway it finally works thank you for your answer